# Integrate Okta with Bubble

Tags: okta, multi-factor-authentication, okta-api

everyone!
I'm new to Bubble and Okta and building a page using Bubble.
I've already implemented login workflow compatible with okta.
Now I'm going to introduce multi-factor authentication provided from okta for password reset workflow.
If I press the 'reset' button, a request that enroll email MFA function in okta should be delivered(I might be wrong..but this is what I have learned from research).
In this case, where does the request reach and how is it structured?

I researched okta documents and other forums, but the answers were different and didn't worked for me.
I'd appreciate it if you help me.
Regards.